# Isomorphism from $SL_2(F_2)$ to Sym(3)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you help me find a isomorphism from $SL_2(F_2)$ to Sym(3). I supose that I have to use vectors. ex. $v_1 (1,0), v_2(1,1), v_3 (0,1)$, but I don't remeber how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the natural action of $SL_2(F_2)$ on the projective line $P^1(F_2)$, which consists of three points $P_1=(1,0),P_2=(1,1),P_3=(0,1)$. Each element $g$ corresponds to a permutation of them. This gives rise to the isomorphism you wanted. You only need to write down this bijection explicitly. For example, the upper triangular element $n$ sends $(1,0)$ to $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ to $(0,1)$, and $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$. So it corresponds to $(23)$ in $Sym(3)$. Hope this helps.